# Is there any ways for me to optimize this java code?

Tags: java, optimization, image-processing

This code should look for images in a folder, and combine the images into a 6000x6000 image. It is working, however it is really slow. Any optimizations I could implement??

```
File in = new File(args[1]);
            File out = new File(args[2]);
    in.mkdirs();
    out.mkdirs();
    if(out.exists())
    {
        out.delete();
    }
    if(!in.isDirectory())
    {
        Main.printUsage();
    }


    BufferedImage bout = new BufferedImage(6032, 6032, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = bout.createGraphics();
    int count = 0;
    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i<=376; i++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<=376; k++)
        {
            File cu = new File(in, (i-188)+"-"+(k-188)+".png");
            if(cu.exists())
            {
                count++;
                try {
                    g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(cu), 16*i, 16*k, null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Runtime.getRuntime().;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Processed "+count+" chunks in "+((System.currentTimeMillis()-starttime)/1000F)+" seconds");

    g.dispose();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bout, "png", out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Which *part* is slow? Where's the time going? Simply adding logging with timestamps may well isolate which bit is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I have modified the source since I compiled it. Nothing too major should be changed

Comment: For optimization of already working code, you should consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The time is going into combining the actual images

Comment: By really slow, I mean an hour. I do not expect it to happen in an instant, but around 5 images per second seems a bit slow

Comment: vizier, That code is for drawing the image it reads onto a bigger one.

Comment: 141,376 images per hour is 141,376 per 3600 seconds or around 39 per second (as opposed to '5').

Comment: *"Nothing too major should be changed"* Unless the code as shown is completely unchanged, it is entirely pointless - noise.  I have removed the noise from the question.  Please look to replace it with ..actual code or, as I *first* suggested, an ***SSCCE.***

Comment: @Andrew, I do not understand why you think it's helpful to remove the code.  It's better than what you've left this question with.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - can you take it down a notch. Yes the code may not compile but your aggressive tone (yelling about "noise") isn't helping matters much either. Removing the code in its entirety devalues the question, it may not compile but at least from what's posted one can infer what it's doing.

Comment: To the OP: I recommend posting a compilable/runnable sample of code that has been profiled to find out where your bottleneck is. If you do that then flag so I can migrate this to our code review site.

Answer (score 2):

The delay is likely in the file system, opening all those files. With that many files in a single directory, even just the lookup time in the directory will be non-trivial.

If this is the case, there won't be a software solution. Try putting the files on a flash drive to see if that helps, even if only as a test.

Comment: A flash drive? As in, a thumb drive, or an SSD? If it's the former (especially with USB 2.0's speeds), that probably won't help...

Comment: @minitech, I was thinking SSD when I wrote it. A thumb drive is probably easier to come by though, and if it works you know the answer. If it doesn't work then you're no worse off.

Answer (score 1):

An image of size 6032*6032 and 2 nested loops each size of 376
Drawing almost 36 million pixles at least 2 times
And looping 141 thousand times

Don't forget reading the files...

I suggest that you try and combine pairs of images using 2 threads

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your application, but you could save your new created image and check if it is up to date before you generate the new one. Or, save some more information and update only the changed parts.

But if everything changes every time you load your program, the bottleneck is clearly the I/O delay. Without money for a SSD or raidsystem you wont come through it ;)